# how to dispatch a generic dialog with redux toolkit correctly?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

**Environment**

- Redux-Toolkit
- React Native
- Typescript

**Background**

I am working on a reusable confirm dialog component that wrapped by a hook.

When the hook is called, the dialog should await the boolean from user's response.

---

**Problem**

My error occurs when I tried to pass **resolve()** from thunk action to store.

It seems this serialiazable error only happens when using redux toolkit.

My question is `What is the correct way to observe the user's onPress inside thunk action.`

[image]

Custom hook for dialog

```
export const useDialog = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  return useCallback(
    (payload: DialogProps) => dispatch(dialogThunkAction(payload)),
    [dispatch],
  );
};
```

Thunk action

```
export const dialogThunkAction = (
  payload: DialogProps,
): AppThunkAction<Promise<boolean | undefined>, DialogProps> => {
  return dispatch =>
    new Promise<boolean | undefined>(async (resolve, reject) => {
      dispatch(settingSlice.actions.setDialogShow(payload));
      resolve(true);
    });
};
```

There are two actions to update the hide show boolean for the dialog.

```
export const settingSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'setting',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setDialogShow: (state, action) => {
      state.dialog = {
        isVisible: true,
        ...action.payload,
      };
    },
    setDialogDismiss: (state, action) => {
      state.dialog = {isVisible: false};
    },
  },
});
```

In screen

```
const dialog = useDialog();
...

<Button
  title={'Delete'}
  onPress={async () => {
    const dialogResponse = await dialog({
      cancelText: 'Cancel',
    }); //target to have resolved response here
  }}
/>
```

I have looked into different docs but they focused on the API calling.

Please point out if I have anything wrong about the design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a warning. Redux is Javascript, and you can pass anything with any action. No one can really stop you. In fact, redux-toolkit gives you opt-out capability for this "error" [in the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/getDefaultMiddleware).

If you're not persisting the non-serializable stuff anywhere, I personally don't have an issue with passing it around in actions; it can be convenient. It's up to the style of the codebase.

However, there's a fairly straightforward alternative: keep an object somewhere that maps string keys to your functions, pass the keys in the actions, and call the functions where the actions are handled. You will also have to pass any args separately.

That's not going to look pretty in your slice; you may want to write a little piece of middleware to handle it elsewhere.  Or you can just turn off the warning.

Comment: So you think it is normal to pass function to redux store and suggest to ignore this error?

Comment: Well, as I said, it's possible, and if it's not persisted, it's not hurting anything.  Some people hate it, others don't mind it.  I don't know if it's "normal" or not.

Comment: could you explain little bit more about persist here?

Comment: When you have data you want to store even after the user has closed the app, you'll want that data to persist somewhere.  The way this is mostly done is to `JSON.stringify` your state and write the string to the device somewhere like AsyncStorage, and then `JSON.parse` it when the app wakes up.  So anything that won't stringify (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description)) will be lost.

Comment: I see, your answer is quite clear to me, thanks!